# Is it good to create Spark batch job for every new Use cases

Tags: apache-spark, batch-processing, bigdata

I run `100s`of computer in a network and `100s`of user access those machines. Every day, thousands or more `syslogs`are generated from all those machines. `Syslog` could be any log including `system failures`, `network, firewall`, `application errors` etc.

Sample log would look like below

```
May 11 11:32:40 scrooge SG_child[1829]: [ID 748625 user.info] m:WR-SG-BLOCK-111-
00 c:Y th:BLOCK , no allow rule matched for request with entryurl:http:url on 
mapping:bali [ rid:T6zcuH8AAAEAAGxyAqYAAAAQ sid:a6bbd3447766384f3bccc3ca31dbd50n ip:192.24.61.1]
```

From the logs, I extract fields like `Timestamp, loghost, msg, process, facility` etc and store them in `HDFS`. `Logs`are stored in `json format`. Now, I want to build a system where I can type a query in a `web application` and do analysis on those `logs`. I would like to be able to do queries like

- get logs where the message contains "Firewall blocked" keywords.
- get logs generated for the User Jason
- get logs containing "Access denied" msg.
- get log count grouped by user, process, loghost etc.
  There could be thousands of different types of analytics I want to do. To add more, I want the combined results of historical data and the real time data i.e. combining batch and realtime results.

Now my questions is

- To get the batch result, I need to run the batch spark jobs. Should I
  be creating batch jobs for every unique query user makes. If I
  do so, I will end up creating 1000s of batch jobs. If not, what kind
  of batch jobs should I run so that I can get results for any type of
  analytics.
- Am I thinking it the right way. If my approach itself is wrong, then do share what should be the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible (via thrift server for example), **Apache Spark main objective is not to be a query engine but building data pipelines** for stream and batch data sources.

If the transformation you are only projecting fields and you want to enable ad-hoc queries, **sounds like you need another data store** - such as ElasticSearch for example. The additional benefit is that it comes with a Kibana that enable analytics to some extent.

Another option is to use a SQL engine such as **Apache Drill**.

Comment: Can you point out which part of my requirement specifically is not meant for Spark.

Comment: "system where I can type a query in a web application and do analysis on those logs" sounds more suitable for elasticsearch or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Spark is probably not the right tool to use unless the size of these logs justifies the choice.

Are these logs in the order of a few gigabytes? Then use splunk.

Are these logs in the order of hundreds of gigabytes? Then use elasticsearch with maybe Kibana on top.

Are they in the order of terabytes? Then you should think to some more powerful analytical architecture and there are many alternatives here that basically do batch jobs in the same way as you would with Spark, but usually in a smarter way.

Comment: Elasticsearch is another kind of tool, for another purpose, which can handle terabytes, even petabytes. It's right that spark is not the right tool for some cases, not all revolves around volume.

Comment: The data volume could go upto Terabytes. Apart from the volume, do you think my use case is not meant for the spark processing.